# Ansible Warning "type list in a string field was converted to type string"

Tags: ansible

I have a task that add Gnome favorites for each user:

```
users:
  - name: username
    email: email@server.com
    favorites: "'pk1.desktop', 'pk2.desktop', 'pk3.desktop', pk4.desktop'"

- name: "[DCONF] Add favorites"
  dconf:
    key: /org/gnome/shell/favorite-apps
    value: "[{{ item.favorites }}]"
    state: present
  become: yes
  become_user: "{{ item.name }}"
  with_items: "{{ users }}"
```

I get this error:

```
[WARNING]: The value ['pk1.desktop', 'pk2.desktop', 'pk3.desktop', pk4.desktop'] (type list) in a string field was converted to u"['pk1.desktop', 'pk2.desktop', 'pk3.desktop', pk4.desktop']" (type string). If this does
not look like what you expect, quote the entire value to ensure it does not change.
```

How could I fix that?

Also, how could I transform this so that it looks like this:

```
users:
  - name: username
    email: email@server.com
    favorites: 
      - 'pk1.desktop'
      - 'pk2.desktop'
      - 'pk3.desktop'
      - 'pk4.desktop'
```

the reason being that I have a lot of those favorites, so that would be easier for me to handle like this, and also because I want to learn how to do that ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your warning message (ansible 2.9.9). Note you have a single quote missing on the last value.

Meanwhile, since you want to transition to declaring your values in a list for simplicity, the following should allow you to do so and fix your issue all together.

```yaml
---
- name: Set favs
  hosts: somehost
  remote_user: someuser

  vars:
    users:
      - name: username
        email: email@server.com
        favorites:
          - pk1.desktop
          - pk2.desktop
          - pk3.desktop
          - pk4.desktop

  tasks:
    - name: "[DCONF] Add favorites"
      dconf:
        key: /org/gnome/shell/favorite-apps
        value: "{{ item.favorites | string }}"
        state: present
      become: yes
      become_user: "{{ item.name }}"
      with_items: "{{ users }}"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. However, it still doesn't work : `failed: [IP] (item={'name': 'username', 'email': 'email', 'favorites': ['pk1.desktop', 'pk2.desktop', 'pk1.desktop3', 'pk1.desktop4']}) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": {"email": "email", "favorites": ["pk1.desktop", "pk2.desktop", "pk3.desktop", "pk4.desktop"], "name": "username"}, "msg": "dconf failed while write the value with error: error: 8:expected value\n\nUsage:\n  dconf write KEY VALUE \n\nWrite a new value to a key\n\nArguments:\n  KEY      A key path (starting, but not ending with '/')\n  VALUE`

Comment: I am not able to reproduce your issue. The above worked without problems (ansible 2.9,9 - ubuntu 18.04). Please do not paster large pieces of codes and error in comments: edit your question instead.

Comment: Oh you're right, I didn't see that you remove the `[]` from `value: "[{{ item.favorites | string }}]"` Thanks a lot!